# Avoiding sub-queries in named scopes

Tags: ruby, sql, mysql, ruby-on-rails

I use named scopes all over the place.

When I have a named scope that deals with two different tables, I tend to query the second table in a sub-query. That way, if I mix and match with other tables I don't need to worry about reusing a table alias or having ambiguous column names that only appear in bizarre scenarios.

For example, suppose I have a `posts` table that is one-to-many related to a `tags` table. I might add a `with_tags` scope on my `Post` model like this:

```
named_scope :with_tags, lambda { |tags|
  tags = [tags] if tags.kind_of? String
  {:conditions => ["id IN (SELECT post_id FROM tags WHERE name IN (?))", tags]}
}
```

However, that doesn't seem ideal. Many databases can use a join more efficiently than they can use a sub-query. A query that looks like this might perform better:

```
SELECT DISTINCT posts.* FROM posts JOIN tags ON posts.id = tags.post_id WHERE tags.name IN (?)
```

How do other people do this? Do you use the `:include/:join` parameters cleverly to know what the aliases `ActiveRecord` will use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use what Rails calls eager loading. This is done with the `:include` parameter in your `AR` call. Add it to your lambda block.